# Set system and full rank of a characteristic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We have a set system $A_1,A_2,\dots A_m$ where $A_i \subseteq [n]$. Given that $|A_i| = k$ and $|A_i \cap A_j| = \lambda \;\;\;\forall i \neq j \;\;\; (  k \text{ and } \lambda \text{ are some positive integers } )\;\;$ . Prove that $m \leq n $.

We represent each set $A_i$ with a vector $V_i$ of size $n$ of zeros and ones (1 in $x^{th}$ place in $V_i$ if $x \in A_i$ otherwise zero) and $B = \begin{bmatrix} 
V_1 \\
V_2 \\
V_3 \\
\dots \\
\dots \\
V_m \\
\end{bmatrix}_{m \times n}
$

then $BB^{T} \text{ becomes } \begin{bmatrix} 
k&\lambda&\lambda&\dots&\lambda \\
\lambda&k&\lambda&\dots&\lambda \\
\lambda&\lambda&k&\dots&\lambda \\
\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots&\dots \\
\lambda&\lambda&k&\dots&k \\
\end{bmatrix}_{m \times m}
$

How to prove that this $BB^{T}$ is of full rank (using the idea of positive definite matrices )? Then we can apply
$n \geq \text{rank}(B) \geq \text{rank}(BB^{T})= m$ to prove that $m \leq n$.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assume without loss of generality that the $A_{i}$ are distinct, and then $\lambda < k$.

Note that
$$
B B^{T} = (k - \lambda) I + \lambda S, 
$$
where
$$
S =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
  &   & \ddots & \\
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So if $B B^{T} v = 0$, for some $v = [v_{1}, \dots, v_{m}]^{T} \ne 0$, we have for each $i$
$$
(k - \lambda) v_{i} = - \lambda \sum_{j=1}^{m} v_{j}
$$
so that all $v_{i}$ are equal, $v_{i} = u \ne 0$ for all $u$, and thus $(k - \lambda) u = - \lambda m u$, and $k = \lambda (1 - m) \le 0$, a contradiction.